# DocBlock documentation for instances of classes

Tags: documentation, phpdoc, docblocks

Could you please give me some guidance on how I should document this piece of code with DocBloc documentation?

```
private $entityManager;

public function __construct($entityManager) {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
}
```

The `$entityManager` is an instance of the EnitiyManager class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For phpdoc, only property annotation is useful.

Also adding constructor typehint to check the type.
But consider, that constructor annotation would not bring any new information.

For more examples, it's good to check some framework source on Github, e.g. [Symfony](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php#L82)

```
/**
 * @var EntityManager
 */
private $entityManager;


/**
 * @var EntityManager $entityManager
 */
public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager) {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
}
```

Comment: I understand that a docblock for the constructror method is redundant. But, if it wasn't, what would it look like?